# Перевод нативного Query запроса в Query methods в spring

Tags: java, sql, spring

Как можно перевести данный Query запрос

```
SELECT * FROM vs_types WHERE 
                        (id, 
                         code,
                         CODE_DESCRIPTION,
                         RECORD_TYPE,
                         TYPE,
                         TYPE_DESCRIPTION,
                         CATEGORY) 
                         IN 
                         (SELECT mytype.id, 
                                 mytype.code,
                                 mytype.CODE_DESCRIPTION,
                                 mytype.RECORD_TYPE,
                                 mytype.TYPE,
                                 mytype.TYPE_DESCRIPTION,
                                 mytype.CATEGORY
                                 FROM vs_types myType WHERE ROWNUM = 1 AND mytype.record_type = vs_types.record_type)` (Oracle)
```

в аналогичный (но так сказать на языке spring-га) по типу findAll() или findByColumnName()

Comment: Конвертируйте WHERE IN в честный JOIN - и всё станет просто и понятно.

Comment: `WHERE ROWNUM = 1` без сортировки - это могуче... "дайте мне одну запись, всё равно какую".